# absolutely positioned parent's rendered width with max-height children in gecko vs others

Tags: html, css-position, css

That title's a mouthful! So I have an absolutely positioned parent element with 100% height, its children `img`s have a 100% `max-height`. Now, while WebKit (Chromium25) and Opera (12) shrink the parent's calculated/rendered width to match the `img`s new (smaller) width, Gecko (FF21) leaves it as the `img`s (collective) original width and the parent appears to have a big right padding.

See here: http://jsfiddle.net/b3TY5/ (huge screen owners: please resize your browser window so the grey images begin scaling down)

Now I've read that `position: absolute` is overused (and I found a workaround to the problem), but I would still be interested in

- a solution that makes Gecko behave like WebKit (IMO WebKit's way is more logical. Or am I wrong?)
- an explanation of the different behaviors, and maybe something like best practices concerning future encounters with this situation (but please be more constructive than "don't use position absolute" ;)

Thanks!

Edit: my workaround isn't perfect, because I end up with the parent element having an 100% width, so I can't have an absolutely positioned child with `right: 0`. When I set the parent to `display: inline-block`, WebKit shows the same behavior as Gecko. Cf. http://jsfiddle.net/b3TY5/1/ and make sure to have a really small result window. Notice the first div's right padding.

Edit2:

1. I'm afraid the solution to the original problem might just be: it's weird. As @Diodeus points out, there's a problem with `position: absolute` vs. `height: 100%`. To me, this never occurred to be a problem: both browser scale images down to the (max-)height of the viewport (even if this not specified) **BUT** their, er, placeholder is, at least horizontally, not scaled correctly, as far as i can tell. This *error margin* increases as the parent container gets smaller. And while WebKit shrinks the parent to neatly wrap its children, it only does so upon page load, not after a resize...
2. In my workaround - devoid of `position: absolute`/`height: 100%` - I discovered a Gecko/WebKit inconsistency: http://jsfiddle.net/b3TY5/3/; with `box-sizing: border-box` (resp. `-moz-box-sizing`) WebKit shrinks the parent to match the childrens' width (blue div smaller than the yellow one) while Gecko does not (blue and yellow div equal width).

Comment: Absolutely-positioned elements are not in the document flow, therefore "100% height" has no context. 100% of what....?

Comment: @Diodeus: …100% of the viewport. At least, that's how they appear. They scale down "correctly" (- that is, as I would expected, even if formally incorrect), while apparently their widths don't. See Edit2.